# events and action methods

Tags: c#, events, action

I've got some kind of a timer. When the time goes out i want to invoke an event. But i don't know how to add a method to the event when i'm making an instance. 
This is the code :

```
public delegate void DaysPassed(Action action);

    public class TimeAwait
    {
        public uint DaysLeft;
        public event DaysPassed Done;

        public TimeAwait(uint daysToWait, Action action)
        {
            DaysLeft = daysToWait;
            Done += action;
        }
```

Comment: So you want to give an default EventHandler at construction time instead of first create the item and then add the Eventhandler?

Comment: when i am creating the item i want to give him a method to invoke when days are passed

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `var ta = new TimeAwait(2 /*days to wait*/, () => { Console.WriteLine("Work is done here"); } /*action as lambda expression*/)`?

Comment: there is a method that reduces the DaysLeft with one every day and when they are gone the event should invoke bud i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need event and delegates here. Just invoke your action in the right place. For example:

```
    public class TimeAwait
    {
        public uint DaysLeft;
        private Action action;
        private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public TimeAwait(uint daysToWait, Action a)
    {
        action = a;
        DaysLeft = daysToWait;

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = daysToWait;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

    }

    public void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        action.Invoke();
        aTimer.Stop();
    }
}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Action someAction;
                someAction = () => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

            var item1 = new TimeAwait(2000, someAction);
            var item2 = new TimeAwait(4000, someAction);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A class like this should do the trick if you just want it to be able to invoke a passed Action. If you want to be able to register other listeners besides the creator you need Events and i wouldn't pass the eventhandlers in a constructor in that case.

```
public class Countdown
{
     int _count;
     Action _onZero;

     public Countdown(int startValue, Action onZero)
     {
          _count = startValue;
          _onZero = onZero;
     }

     public void Tick()
     {
         if(_count == 0)
             return; //or throw exception

         _count--;
         if(_count == 0)
            _onZero();
     }
}
```